# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Link Error 1104

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, sdl, linker-errors

A while ago I attempted to make make a game using c++ and SDL. I am now taking a class that requires me to program in C++ and I would like to use VS as the IDE. I uninstalled VS 2012 and upgraded to 2013. I am able to compile c# code but when I make a c++ project I get the error

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'SDL.lib'

I went to the project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> input and made sure that SDL was not referenced there. My Additional Dependencies now has the value %(AdditionalDependencies). The rest of the options are blank. I also made sure that in VC++ Directories the Include Directories did not include anything related to SDL. Having done all of this I still get the same error. Is is somehow inheriting the SDL linker. The project only contains a hello world program which does not include any other libraries. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SDL has a knack for doing many things behind your back.  Meant to keep newbie programmers out of trouble, that's a double-edged sword when you try to get rid of it again.  Try View + (Other Windows) + Property Manager and look through the nodes for anything that quacks sdl.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Right click the project and choose *Properties*.
2. Open *Configuration Properties --> Linker -->Input*.
3. In the *Ignore Specific Default Libraries* entry, add **SDL.lib**.

BTW, whatever you add in your *Include Directories* cannot cause a linkage error (and neither can any `include` that you have in your project).